# How to integrate zend framework 2 with mongo db

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zend-form2

I am trying to integrate zend framework 2 with Mongo DB , can someone please provide the steps or any links to do so.

Query: Can integration be done without using Doctrine 2?

Comment: Can you give more information about what you've tried that didn't work? There are tools to integrate Zend and MongoDB here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/PHP+Libraries,+Frameworks,+and+Tools#PHPLibraries%2CFrameworks%2CandTools-ZendFramework

Comment: Trying to connect Zend Framework Skeleton Applicatio to Mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

The pre-requisite is that you'll need to install the PECL MongoDB driver:

```
% sudo `which pecl` install mongo
% sudo sh -c 'echo "extension=mongo.so" > /usr/local/zend/etc/ext.d/mongo.ini'
% sudo ln -nfs /usr/local/zend/etc/ext.d/mongo.ini /usr/local/zend/etc/conf.d/
% sudo `which service` apache2 restart
% if [ `php -m|grep -i mongo` ]; then echo mongodb is installed; else echo mongodb has not been installed; fi
```

**NOTE**: This assumes you are using Zend Server CE. If not, the `mongo.ini` file will need to be created in the directory that your distribution designates as the extension directory:

```
%   php-config --extension-dir
```

Once you've gotten that all setup, you can following the tutorial from the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/mongo.tutorial).